Unable to correctly configure a dependent field in Power Apps Form
I have created a form in Power Apps as below:

The form should show all the zones for the operations selected in the Operations field.
However, currently the form only shows Zones for only 1 Operation selected in the Operations field. When multiple operations, the Zone field only lists the zones related to the first selected operation.
I am using the following code in the Items property for the Combo Box for Zones
If(
  ddselection.SelectedText.Value = "Zones",
  Switch(
    First(cboperations.SelectedItems).Value,
    "Operation 1", ["O1Z1", "O1Z2", "O1Z3"],
    "Operation 2", ["O2Z1", "O2Z2", "O2Z3", "O2Z4", "O2Z5"],
    "Operation 3", ["O3Z1", "O3Z2", "O3Z3", "O3Z4"],
    []
  ),
  []
)

But this code does not show all zones related to the selected operations in Operations field.

You can try something similar to:
With({
  opTable: Table(
    { op: "Operation 1", zns: "O1Z1|O1Z2|O1Z3" },
    { op: "Operation 2", zns: "O2Z1|O2Z2|O2Z3|O2Z4|O2Z5" },
    { op: "Operation 3", zns: "O3Z1|O3Z2|O3Z3|O3Z4" }
  )},
  Split(Concat(
    Filter(opTable, op in cboperations.SelectedItems.Value),
     zns, "|"), "|"
  )
)

